# Symfony 4 FosUserBundle - error on /register route - cannot find User entity

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Installing FOSUserBundle I got the following error when trying to access /register:

> Class 'AppBundle\Entity\User' not found

Well, here is the User entity, which is under /src/Entity/User.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

Otherwise, FOS was able to generate the user table on the db and also all the routes were created.

Also FOS's /login route works fine insofar as it shows the login form.

FOS's configuration is under /config/packages/fos_user.yaml and looks like this:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "my.email@example.com"
        sender_name: "myname"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace specify an AppBundle but you say that your file is in `/src/Entity/User.php`.

Put it in `/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was used to have an AppBundle on another installation, because I had a different setup. For this one I do not believe I need an AppBundle as such, so I have changed User.php namespace to App\Entity and correspondingly over at fos_user.yaml, ie, user_class: \App\Entity\User.

Comment: Glad it helped ;)